# Template on class and method are related. How to prevent combinations?

Tags: c++, templates, swig

I have the following situation.

```
template <class T>
class Foo {

    template <class V>
    int bar();

};
```

(I am using swig to port this class to python, to clarify)
The problem I have occurs because the actual template arguments T and V are related, that is `Foo<T1>` should have `bar<V1>`, `Foo<T2>` should have `bar<V2>` and so on. However, I am in the situation where swig (or the C++ compiler) pretends to have all the possible combinations defined, that is `Foo<T1>::bar<V1>`, `Foo<T1>::bar<V2>`, `Foo<T2>::bar<V1>` and so on. This means that I have to provide Tn * Vn methods, most of them raising an exception, except for the diagonal combination Ti/Vi

Is there a way to prevent this in a smart way, or should I just bite the dust and implement all the combinations? If you think I have a design problem, how would you solve it ?

Comment: Why is `bar` a function template then? It can just use `T`.

Comment: @sftrabbit: because inside it uses type V to perform some manipulations, and this type is related to T.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the `V`s. I thought it was all `T`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's 1-1 mapping between `T`s and `V`s, why does `bar` need to be a template? You could create a trait class to determine the proper `V`, like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Match_T_V;

template <>
struct Match_T_V<T1> {
  typedef V1 type;
};

template <>
struct Match_T_V<T2> {
  typedef V2 type;
};

//etc. for other Ts


template <typename T>
class Foo {
  typedef typename Match_T_V<T>::type V;

  int bar();  //use V, guaranteed to be the correct one
};
```

Comment: That's an interesting pattern.

Comment: @StefanoBorini Trait classes are actually a pretty common template programming technique, one of the basic building blocks of template metaprogramming.

Comment: I never programmed with templates. Mostly of my experience in C++ is with plain OOP

Comment: This is a nicely flexible approach.  When it makes sense to add a typedef in `T` saying what `V` should be that's even simpler: e.g. a class templated on a container type might reasonably have a function taking `T::const_iterator`.